# Quadruped is moving very slow when i try to publish odom topic

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-plugin, base-odometry

Hi i am currently working on unitree A1 in ubuntu 18.04 ROS Melodic. I have installed all the unitree_ros and unitree_guide packages in my catkin_ws workspace. i am able to control the quadruped in the gazebo simulation using ./devel/lib/unitree_guide/junior_ctrl.

But i tried to modify the gazebo.xacro code to publish cmd_vel and odom, the code is as per below:

[image]

When i try to run the simulation the quadruped moves very slow. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Please paste the code, and not a screenshot, as images are not text-searchable